# How do I write in vba to capture columns from multiple sheets into one dictionary object excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have 12 sheets with data in the same columns that I want all in one dictionary object. I don't understand the dictionary object well. I am hoping that I can assign all 12 sheets (2 rows per sheet) in one statement. If not, would I have to loop through 12 times and somehow assign that way? Thank you.  geddeca

Here is the code that worked successfully to capture 2 columns into one dictionary object.

```
Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
dict.comparemode = vbTextCompare
With Worksheets(w)

        'collect values from worksheet
        arr = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Value2
        Debug.Print w

        'process dictionary of list and count
        dict.RemoveAll ... more code
```

This is the code that I loop through the sheets with for individual sheet totals.
This won't work for what I am looking for. two columns of data from grabbed from the 12 sheets and then sorted according to the unique identifiers.

```
Sub CREBSort()

Dim i As Long, j As Long, w As Long
Dim arr As Variant, dict As Object
Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim rowString As String

Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
dict.comparemode = vbTextCompare

WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
Debug.Print WS_Count
rowString = ""


For w = 1 To WS_Count
    With Worksheets(w)

        'collect values from worksheet
        arr = .Range(.Cells(2, "L"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp)).Value2
        Debug.Print w

        'process dictionary of list and count
        dict.RemoveAll

        '        Debug.Print "The array is: "

        For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        rowString = arr(i, 1)
             For j = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
                dict.Item(arr(i, j)) = dict.Item(arr(i, j)) + 1

             Next j

        Next i
'return new values to worksheet
        .Cells(1, "W").Resize(1, 2) = Array("list", "count")
        .Cells(2, "W").Resize(dict.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(dict.Keys)
        .Cells(2, "X").Resize(dict.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
        'sort values by count descending then name ascending
         With .Range(.Cells(1, "W"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "X").End(xlUp))
            .Sort key1:=.Columns(2), order1:=xlDescending, _
                  key2:=.Columns(1), order2:=xlAscending, _
                  Header:=xlYes
        End With

 End With
Next w


End Sub
```

Comment: You must loop through the 12 sheets... i'd do a loop using the array and then filling de dictionary from the array, erase it and start back

Comment: I have done that for individual sheet totals.(see total code above)  But I don't think that will work for a mass total of the 12 sheets sorted as I need it. It has to be in one dictionary I think.  Thank you.

Comment: why are you using this `dict.RemoveAll`? you are deleting the dictionary on every iteration

Comment: Yes in that code My objective is to have the columns sorted on each sheet separately.  one sheet for each month of sales.   But as I thought about how to have another yearly column sorted in order of sales company and the matching yearly total I realized that I my code needed adjusting.  Each month there are some sales company that have more sales than others. Putting the columns side by side and totalling the sales won't work because the rows don't match up. I thought one big range then sort at the end would work. Hope that makes. sense.  I have to go out for a bit and can't answer.

Comment: @geddeca - could you specify your sheet structure giving some examples plus a possible output structure by re-editing your OP? What do you mean by *"(2 rows per sheet)"*?

Comment: Actually Damians answer fixed the problem. I didn't understand that I could just add to the dictionary on every iteration. so took dict.removall out and it worked perfectly.